# Launching fire-and-forget coroutines from non-suspend functions using CoroutineScope

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I have a Kotlin application where we are unable to use `runBlocking()` from an app entry point (like `main`).  I've found that I can do the following to do a fire-and-forget asynchronous operation, but I'm unclear on whether this is a good practice -- I see this in the docs:

> Do not replace GlobalScope.launch { ... } with CoroutineScope().launch { ... } constructor function call. The latter has the same pitfalls as GlobalScope.

But I've also seen places where people seem to be recommending this approach.  Here's an example of the approach:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

fun doStuff(): String {
    val response = "all done"
    println("before fireAndForget")

    fireAndForget()

    println("after fireAndForget")
    return response
}

fun fireAndForget() {
    scope.launch {
        makeSomeExpensiveCall()
    }
}

fun makeSomeExpensiveCall() {
    // In reality, make a blocking database call, etc. without coroutines, reactive, etc.
    Thread.sleep(100)
    println("after sleep")
}

fun main() {
    val response = doStuff()
    Thread.sleep(200)
    println(response)
}
```

The above prints the following, which is what I expect.  I just don't know if it's safe to do this.

```
before fireAndForget
after fireAndForget
after sleep
all done
```

EDIT:

The below is a bit more realistic version of what I'm trying to do.  I'm still unsure of whether the `scope` is being set up and used correctly.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.SupervisorJob
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class Controller {
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob())

    fun saveDataToDatabase(): String {
        saveRecord()

        println("before saveAuditDataWithoutBlocking")
        saveAuditDataWithoutBlocking()
        println("after saveAuditDataWithoutBlocking")

        return "Save succeeded"
    }

    private fun saveRecord() {
        Thread.sleep(10)
    }

    private fun saveAuditDataWithoutBlocking() {
        // Write more data to a database, but do not block caller
        val job = scope.launch {
            saveAuditInfoBlocking()
        }

        job.invokeOnCompletion { throwable ->
            throwable?.let {
                println("Exception in fireAndForget: $throwable")
            }
        }

        // Is there something else I need to do?
    }

    private fun saveAuditInfoBlocking() {
        Thread.sleep(100)
        println("Finished slow write of audit data")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val controller = Controller()
    println("Calling saveDataToDatabase()")
    val response = controller.saveDataToDatabase()
    println("Received response in main(): $response")
    Thread.sleep(200)
    println("main() finished")
}
```

Output:

```
Calling saveDataToDatabase()
before saveAuditDataWithoutBlocking
after saveAuditDataWithoutBlocking
Received response in main(): Save succeeded
Finished slow write of audit data
main() finished
```

Answer (score 3):

GlobalScope's documentation says the purpose for which it is OK to use:

> Global scope is used to launch top-level coroutines which are operating on the whole application lifetime and are not cancelled prematurely.

The reason you *usually* want to avoid it is that in most applications, almost everything has some scope to it that is limited. For instance, if you are doing some action on some screen of your app, you want to cancel that action when you move to a different screen so you aren't leaking resources.

But if you are doing something that should last for the lifetime for the app, such that you can't possibly be hanging onto some resource in your coroutine for longer than you want to, then GlobalScope is appropriate.

You have to be really careful though. Consider this psuedo-code:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    val url = viewLayout.someTextField.textEnteredByUser
    someApi.downloadFileToAppResourceDirectory(url) // a cancellable suspend function
}
```

This is a task that you never want to be cancelled because you want to keep downloading the file even if the user navigates away from this screen, so you think, this is a job for GlobalScope! But the problem is that you have referenced a screen element `viewLayout` in your coroutine, so a reference to the entire layout of this screen is captured by the coroutine that will outlive your screen. This is a memory leak.

Since it is so easy to create memory leaks with GlobalScope, they annotate it with `@DelicateCoroutinesApi` to discourage its use. So then, some naïve users create a one-off CoroutineScope to run a single coroutine (i.e. `CoroutineScope().launch { ... }`). This avoids the warning from `@DelicateCoroutinesApi` without changing the behavior it's warning you about.

Incidentally, the way to fix the code above would be to move the first line out of the coroutine so the `url` alone is captured by the coroutine.

---

The code you quoted is a little weird. They have created a CoroutineScope that:

1. Will die the first time any of its children coroutines have a failure, and thereafter never be usable again. Not something I would combine with a "fire-and-forget" example. It's more like "*maybe* fire and forget". `SupervisorScope()` would be more appropriate.
2. There's not much point in creating a CoroutineScope if you aren't going to manage its life, that is, `cancel()` it when its associated scope is destroyed. GlobalScope can be used instead for less convoluted code unless you truly want the behavior mentioned in the point above.

Since it shows some made-up pointless task that doesn't hang onto resources, it doesn't really matter that it's never cancelled, but it could just as well have been a GlobalScope.

The documentation you quoted is talking about creating a CoroutineScope with the constructor call `CoroutineScope()`, and immediately calling `launch` on it without first storing it in a property so you can cancel it at the appropriate time. This code example is not exactly what they're talking about, although it's similar since they create a CoroutineScope and then never call `cancel()` on it.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that this was wrong and that I'd at minimum need to add `cancel()`, etc.  Maybe my question should be: how do I do a fire-and-forget correctly in a situation like this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "situation like this"? The example you give is a contrived one at the top level `main` function of the app, and it's an app that lives for 1 second so there's no reason to worry about memory leaks. You would just use GlobalScope in this case, but it's not a realistic case.

Comment: I mean a situation where we have a function that cannot be converted to a suspending function and need to call a blocking, I/O-intensive function asynchronously.  E.g., we have a controller that calls a service, and that service might have 10 methods, each of which need to fire an asynchronous call like this, but those service methods themselves are not called from coroutines.

Comment: The example code in `fireAndForget()` in your example is correct. The only question left is which scope is appropriate to use for launching the coroutine inside `fireAndForget()`, and the answer depends on what exactly you are doing inside the coroutine. In the vast majority of cases, we use a CoroutineScope that was created with `SupervisorScope()` and is cancelled when the current lifecycle of whatever piece of the app you're in is destroyed. On Android, these are provided for you for Activities, Fragments, and ViewModels via `lifecycleScope` or `viewModelScope`.

Comment: You might have other classes for you app that you build that have different lifecycles than those, so you would create your own SupervisorScope that you cancel at the appropriate time. If your coroutine does something that must not be cancelled, then you design your coroutine not to capture references to anything that might be destroyed, and then run it on GlobalScope.

Comment: Thanks.  Would using a `CoroutineExceptionHandler` and something like `val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + coroutineExceptionHandler + SupervisorJob())` be better?

Comment: To add more context, I'm using a framework that is not normally used with kotlin, let alone coroutines. The controller inherits from a superclass, so I can't make the controller methods `suspend`.

Comment: Better than what? The best way to handle this particular framework probably depends on the details of how it works and also probably opinion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252856/discussion-between-bryan-and-tenfour04).